# Prevent custom weight from being overwritten

Tags: magento2, quote, plugin, product-weight

In my **Magento 2** extension I do calculate the product weight when the user adds an item to the cart.

My problem is that the weight I set gets overwritten at the checkout.
Cause is the `setProduct()` function of `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item.php.`

To prevent this I created a plugin:

> Vendor\Module\Plugin\ItemModelPlugin.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item as QuoteItem;

class ItemModelPlugin
{

    public function aroundSetProduct(QuoteItem $subject, \Closure $proceed, $product)
    {

        if($product->getData('isCalcWeight') == true)
        {
            $weight = $subject->getWeight();
            $result =  $proceed($product);
            $subject->setWeight($weight);
            $subject->save();

        }else {

            $result =  $proceed($product);

        }

        return $result;

    }
}
```

But two things don't work here.

`$product->getData('isCalcWeight')` and `$subject->getWeight()` always return `NULL`.

> **Note:** The attribute "isCalcWeight" is a bool that is set to true/false depending on the fact if a custom weight is used or not.

Can someone help me out here?

**UPDATE**

Something to add is that I need to calculate my weight beforehand, because it is calculated with an ajax request which takes the chosen product options and returns the calculated price and weight for the product. Calculating this every time the product is set would makes things slow, unnecessarily complicated and possibly prone to bugs.

Comment: Not enough information. How do you calculate something for a *product* and *save it* in your extension. Remember that products aren't things you put in a cart. Products are the blueprints for things you put in your cart. It's probably better to store the weight on the cart object or the user's session and then apply it when the product is converted to item, so **after** `setProduct()` is called.

Comment: The weight is not stored in the product, it is stored in the quote item `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item`

Comment: Then... is possible that ajax request has not ended yet when your plugin executes?

Comment: nope, the ajax request was executed in the product view and the value is already written into the table `quote_item`. The method returns `NULL` when the plugin is executed at the checkout.

Comment: You should [debug](https://xdebug.org/) that request and look at the data store (`$this->_data`) for that product. It's possible the `isCalcWeight` attribute is simply not fetched or spelled slightly different.

Comment: I'll look into that, although I don't think that is the problem here, if I don't check `isCalcWeight` the method `$subject->getWeight()` still returns NULL.

Comment: Hey @TrytoFly were you able to find a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking `setProduct()` method...

```
public function setProduct($product)
{
    if ($this->getQuote()) {
        $product->setStoreId($this->getQuote()->getStoreId());
        $product->setCustomerGroupId($this->getQuote()->getCustomerGroupId());
    }
    $this->setData('product', $product)
        ->setProductId($product->getId())
        ->setProductType($product->getTypeId())
        ->setSku($this->getProduct()->getSku())
        ->setName($product->getName())
        ->setWeight($this->getProduct()->getWeight())
        ->setTaxClassId($product->getTaxClassId())
        ->setBaseCost($product->getCost());

    $stockItem = $product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
    $this->setIsQtyDecimal($stockItem ? $stockItem->getIsQtyDecimal() : false);

    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        'sales_quote_item_set_product',
        ['product' => $product, 'quote_item' => $this]
    );

    return $this;
}
```

Why not changing your plugin and making it for **Magento\Catalog\Model\Product** `getWeight()`, using the **after** approach?

Another way could use sales_quote_item_set_product event, to update **QuoteItem** `weight` value

I see both ways easier to get results than your **around** plugin

Comment: I can't use the after method, because I calculate the weight beforehand. See question update.